# How do I add a class to a dojo widget?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to add multiple classes to the widget below for styling purposes:

```
var filteringSelect = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    id: "test",
},
"test");
```

How would I accomplish this?

Here is the actual html:

```
 <div tabindex="-1" wairole="combobox" dojoattachpoint="comboNode" dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onMouse,onmouseleave:_onMouse,onmousedown:_onMouse" id="widget_test" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft dijitComboBox" role="combobox" widgetid="test">
        <div style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div dojoattachevent="onmousedown:_onArrowMouseDown,onmouseup:_onMouse,onmouseenter:_onMouse,onmouseleave:_onMouse" wairole="presentation" dojoattachpoint="downArrowNode" class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton" role="presentation">
                <div class="dijitArrowButtonInner">
                    &thinsp;
                </div>
                <div class="dijitArrowButtonChar">
                    ▼
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationIcon">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationIconText">
                Χ
            </div>
            <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField">
                <input type="text" waistate="haspopup-true,autocomplete-list" wairole="textbox" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" dojoattachevent="onkeypress:_onKeyPress,compositionend" class="dijitReset" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-invalid="false" id="test" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" value="United States"><input type="text" style="display: none;" name="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
dojo.addClass(filteringSelect.domNode, "yourClass");
```

This also handles the situations in which a DOM node already contains "youClass" as a CSS class so that duplicates aren't added.  dojo also provides other methods to handle CSS class management with dojo.removeClass() and dojo.toggleClass().

http://staging.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/addClass.html

Comment: so it would be    dojo.addClass(filteringSelect.test, "ClassName"); or would it be the input tag?

Comment: no, you should do filteringSelect.domNode because the domNode property provides a reference to the actual DOM node in you HTML.  filteringSelect.test would result in a NPE.

Comment: Also, filteringSelect provides a reference to a dijit widget, which provides you with a bunch of dijit API methods - not the actual HTML DOM element.

Comment: So I it would be dojo.addClass(filteringSelect.input, "ClassName"); Correct?

Comment: no, use filteringSelect.domNode because input is not a property of dijit.form.FilteringSelect (http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dijit.form.FilteringSelect). Also, sometimes widgets completely change the original node in which they are applied to, so your "test" node may not even exist after instantiation.

Comment: I pasted the html code above that is rendered. What domNode should I be using?

Comment: FYI you should also ostensibly be able to specify class directly in the parameters for the widget, e.g. `new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({ /*...*/ "class": "myClass"});`

Answer (score 2):

Further working methods:

(1) The procedural version, creating the widget from script:

```
var filteringSelect = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    id: "test",
    class: "myClassName"
},
"test");
```

(2) If you set simply the "class" attribute, it will call in the `dijit/_WidgetBase.js` the setter function `_setClassAttr`, which does exactly what you want:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/SomeThing" class="myClassName"></div>
```

(3) You can set the dojo properties of the widget, as here:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/SomeThing" data-dojo-props="class: 'myClassName'"></div>
```